# Adding factors to an mle2 model

Tags: r, mle

As a reproducible example please see the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
TDT <- data.table(Country = c(rep("A",30),rep("B",50), rep("C",20)),
                      Id = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                      Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                      Country = c(rep("Albania",30),rep("Belarus",50), rep("Chilipepper",20)), 
                      norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                      Income = sample(100,100),
                      Happiness = sample(10,10),
                      Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                      Age = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                      Educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))
TDT [, ID := .I]
TDT$Country <- as.factor(TDT$Country)
#################################################################################################
start_rho <- c(1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2)
mu_Happiness <- mean(TDT$Happiness, na.rm=TRUE)
sd_Happiness <- sd(TDT$Happiness, na.rm=TRUE)


LL4 <- function(p, a, mu, sigma) {
  -sum(dnorm(TDT$Happiness - a*((TDT$Income^(1-p)-1)/(1-p)) + TDT$Sex + TDT$Age + TDT$Educ, mu, sigma, log=TRUE))
}

mle2(LL4, start = list(p = 0.2, sigma=sd_Happiness, mu=mu_Happiness, a=1) , fixed = NULL, method = "BFGS")
```

Now, a paper I am trying to reproduce tells me that `a` is allowed to differ per country, so I want to add `a*Country` to the model resulting in:

```
LL4 <- function(p, a, mu, sigma) {
    -sum(dnorm(TDT$Happiness - a*((TDT$Income^(1-p)-1)/(1-p)) + a*TDT$Country + TDT$Sex + TDT$Age + TDT$Educ, mu, sigma, log=TRUE))
}

mle2(LL4, start = list(p = 0.2, sigma=sd_Happiness, mu=mu_Happiness, a=1) , fixed = NULL, method = "BFGS")
```

I get:

```
Error in optim(par = c(p = 0.2, a = 1, mu = 5.5, sigma = 2.88675134594813 : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(a, TDT$Country) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
```

How do I properly add a factor to this model?

Comment: You should use k-1 dummy 0/1 variables (`Country1`, `Country2`, ..., `Countryk_1`) instead of the k-categories `Country` variable.

Comment: Thanks, good to know! I have about 100 countries however. Does that mean I have to create 100 dummy variables for this? Any "cheats" for this?

Comment: Yes. Of course, if `a` is allowed to vary between countries, `a` will be a vector of length=100.

Comment: Hmm.. So how would I syntactically allow for `a` to be a vector that varies per country?